# c++/cli c# winforms cross-thread operation sometimes possible

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, c++-cli

I am using c++/cli (should also apply to c#) and creating a winforms program.

I have some lines of code that edit data in a DataGridView. The code is executed by an FileSystemWatcher event, but it could be executed by a background worker or a simple thread. However, it is NOT executed by the UI thread.
The DGV is placed on a tab of a TabControl. When the code is executed while the DGV-containing tab has the focus, the code fails with the well-known and expected exception "*Cross-thread operation not valid*".

But when another tab has the focus, the code executes smoothly. I assume that the DGV is not updated when it's not shown, causing the code to work well in this case. But this means that the sending of messages like WM_PAINT to the message queue depends on the visibility (shown or not) of the DGV, and in case it is not visible, those messages must be sent when the DGV gets shown again.

Is this correct?
What are the differences in code exection when the DGV is (not) shown?

Comment: It's very difficult to give you an exact reason why your code behaves as it does without a code snippet. Is the code that does the updating in a background worker or something along those lines?

Comment: The code is executed by a FileSystemWatcher event, but it's basically the same as being executed by a background worker or a thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fundamentally wrong, but that does not mean that you are guaranteed to be reminded about it.  It won't bomb when the control is not visible, no need to update it so no need to do anything that's thread-unsafe so no exception.

You **must** fix the underlying problem.  Very easy to do with the [FileSystemWatcher::SynchronizingObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.synchronizingobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.  Just set it to *this* in the form constructor.  Now the event is automatically raised on the UI thread and you can party on the control properties without being rapped on the knuckles.  Fix:

```
    MyForm(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        fileSystemWatcher1->SynchronizingObject = this;
    }
```

With the assumption that you dropped the FSW from the toolbox onto your form.  Tweak as needed.

Comment: Why is it fundamentally wrong, what is the underlying problem? Is there any other thing wrong except not accessing the DGV via invoke? I was going to use invocation and thereby fix the problem, so I know why it failed. I was more asking for the reason of the "sometimes crash". Nevertheless thanks for pointing to that simple solution. But please answer the question.

Comment: FSW raises its events on a worker thread when you don't use the SynchronizingObject property.  A worker thread is not allowed to update UI directly, it is only legal to do so from the UI thread.  Or in other words, controls are not thread-safe.  Beyond SynchronizingObject, using the form's BeginInvoke() method is another workaround.

Comment: I know that the FSW runs on another thread and that updating UI controls is only allowed from the UI thread. I DO NOT want to be told why it fails when the DGV is visible (because I already know it). I WANT TO know why it DOES NOT fail when the DGV is not shown. What is the difference in this case?

Comment: I explained this in the first paragraph.  It isn't visible when you switch tabs, no need to update it, no need to use thread-unsafe code, no exception.  Code that doesn't run cannot throw exceptions.  I can't think of another way to say it, should be a bit intuitive.

Comment: Okay, this means that the DGV is only updated when it is visible, and when it is not visible, it is updated when it becomes visible? That makes sense. I just did not get that "no need to update it" means that is not updated actually. Understanding problem on my side. Thanks for clarification.