# Winforms Cross thread operation is valid sometimes. Can somebody explain?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

In a winforms application **Cross-thread operation is not valid**. As far as I know we cannot modify a control created in the UI thread using any other thread. We should delegate any such modifications using Control.Invoke method.

I noticed a different behavior. We can modify a few properties from other threads but not all. Check out the below minimal code.

```
new Thread(() =>
{
    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap("path-to-file"); // Works fine. Replaces the old picture with the new one. 
}).Start();

new Thread(() =>
{
    pictureBox1.Size = new Size(100, 100); // Throws error
}).Start();

new Thread(() => {
    label1.BackColor = Color.Red; // Works fine. Changes the background color.
}).Start();

new Thread(() => {
    label1.Text = "SomeText"; // Throws error
}).Start();
```

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790014/c-cli-c-sharp-winforms-cross-thread-operation-sometimes-possible) which explains that it might happen when the control is not in view. But in my case the controls are always visible.

Can somebody explain the reason behind this behavior?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it throwing the same exception each time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first sentance of the answer you linked to still applies to you *"Your code is fundamentally wrong, but that does not mean that you are guaranteed to be reminded about it."*

You are told by the makers of the API (Microsoft) that you should never call anything on a control while not on the UI thread. It is not thier responsibility to warn you any time you do not follow their instructions. Yes, it does not throw a exception right now but that does not mean it will never throw a exception or give you unexpected behavior later.

Comment: the sentence quoted by you is correct. But that post also says that *It won't bomb when the control is not visible*. In my case the control is always visible. Can there be any further explanation possible?

Comment: @BharatGupta people are lazy, whoever wrote the `Image` class did not take the extra time to put the cross-thread check calls on every possible property. so the new properties defined in `Image` likely don't warn you but the ones it inherited from `Control` will. The warning is a convenience thing, just because no one yelled at you that you are doing it wrong does not necessarily mean you are doing it right, it just means no one feels like yelling right now.

Comment: Your reply makes sense. And yeah... I enjoyed your reply :)